# save lucene index to a stream rather than to a directory

Tags: lucene.net

I would like to save a lucene index to a stream, rather than to a directory directly.
So that I can save it into whatever takes a stream.
As far as I understood it, the
    RAMDirecory
object does not really offer a stream for in or output.
At least that's what I understood from the documentation.

Do I have to implement my own
    Directory
implementation like
    StreamDirectory
?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your index take updates?

Comment: Not planned for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not sure why you would want to do this. Just populate the index with FSDirectory; call Optimize. Sure it's not a single stream but it's a small number of files.

If it's a small number of docs (<1M) serialize however you want, then load into a RamDirectory?

You would have to create your own Directory. Perhaps a straight forward way to abstract the file system would be to use a zip file underneath. You could then just abstract the expected files into that.

Comment: I want to save the index to something else than a hard drive.
like a database, or a google drive

Comment: I think you're in for a lot of pain tying to do this. And very poor performance. If you could explain the actual requirement, maybe we can offer an alternative approach

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, however, isn't it a rather circumstantial claim that you would get very poor performance from storing your index in a database (In abstract terms) - I am fairly sure that RavenDB stores it's lucene index in a LMDB implementation. (AKA a database) - And after all, the file system it self in abstract can be seen as a database. Obviously we need a very specialized database, and preferably a "local" one for it to make sense, but still. The File system isn't necessarily the most optimal "database" for this purpose (Although it's adequate for most cases).

Comment: you are absolutely right, with the caveat being that it is a "specialized", optimized for the things Lucene wants to do. It's always "bytes on disk" in the end :)
RavenDB does indeed use a non-file store. But it is based on a highly customized version of Lucene particularly a custom Directory type that uses their custom LMDB like store.
My assumption in the negative answer was based on the assumption of sql as the "database" or "streams" stored in GDrive etc You can't just replace file-on-disk with blob-in-row or stream-on-remote.
You can look at a custom Directory, but this is a adventure!

Comment: additional... this is based on my understanding Lucene.net 3.
Lucene.net 4.8 (I think) has a whole new FST based system. Maybe the storage/persistence approach is more open too ?